# Flexbox - Using "Space-between" whilst aligning items left

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm attempting to implement flexbox and have hit a brick wall. I have a row of items that can range from 1 to 4. When all four items are visible, the "space-between" attribute works perfectly ensuring the space between each items are correct and doesn't have a space on the left of the first item, or the right of the last item. The entire container is taken up. This is great.

However, if I have 2 or 3 items, it goes a bit wrong. Flexbox naturally provides a space between those items. If there are 2 items, one is aligned left and the other right. If there are three, the second is naturally in the centre.

The issue I'm having is that I want to be able to define the widths of my items, but not the margins. Otherwise during the responsiveness I would have to eliminate the margins on odd / evens / first / last etc to ensure the entire container is taken up.

Is there a way to use the "space-between" functionality to automatically adopt the correct margins between each item, but ensure all items are aligned to the left if there are less than 4?

My example below shows the natural outcomes. The last item is how i'd like it to work. I have however had to define a margin for each, something I want to avoid.

Any help would be appreciated.

```css
.row {
  width:1280px;
  margin:0 auto 0;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  background:#ebebeb;
}

ul {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
}

li {
  width:23%;
  background:#999
}

.row--ideal ul {
    justify-content:flex-start;  
}

.row--ideal ul li {
  margin-right:35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <ul>
    <li> Item 1 </li>
    <li> Item 2 </li>
    <li> Item 3 </li>
    <li> Item 4 </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <ul>
    <li> Item 1 </li>
    <li> Item 2 </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <ul>
    <li> Item 1 </li>
    <li> Item 2 </li>
    <li> Item 3 </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="row row--ideal">
  <h3>Ideal Result</h3>
  <ul>
    <li> Item 1 </li>
    <li> Item 2 </li>
    <li> Item 3 </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: with `flexbox` I guess the *simple* way to do is to create an *invisible* element using `visibility: hidden` in case of 3 `li`s for instance...

Comment: I dont understand why you say that during responsive you will have to change things. You have set `width: 23%`, It does not matter screen size, it will take just 23%. I think you should remove `space-between` and use `margin-right: 1%;` and `margin-left: 1%;`, take a look at [this fiddle](http://codepen.io/facundo_larocca/pen/wgyGbY)

Comment: In this instance I will be unable to tell how many items I'll have. So I might have 1 panel, 2 panels, 3 panels. It's data aggregated from a content management system. Unfortunately (if i understand your suggestion correctly...) would mean I would need to work out how many items are missing and create missing elements to fill in the gaps. If that's the case, it won't work in this instance I'm afraid. I'm looking for a way to keep the syntax of the HTML and CSS clean without any hacks.

Comment: @FacundoLaRocca - As I mentioned, having no margins on the far left item and far right item is working great. I don't want margins there. Your example introduces margins. I have other content on the page that needs to align. Therefore, these items need to be evenly distributed. Otherwise I'd just use "space-around". During responsive mode items will got to 48%, and then 100%.

Comment: Mmm, I think you will not be able to do things in the way you would like. Usually make things responsive implies change the way it behaves. My suggestion is try to think in term of screen size, if you were in a desktop, probably you'd render 4 columns, if you were in a tablet, probably you'd render two or three columns, but also if you were in a mobile you'd reder just one.

Comment: @FacundoLaRocca - Thanks. That's what I have mentioned above. 23% at desktop (4 items at max) / 48% at tablet (2 by 2) / 100% on tablet. I have that handled if all four items are present. When there aren't four is where the issue is :(

Comment: I'm trying to find a way, but all of them end modifying code...

Comment: Thanks @FacundoLaRocca - This is the road block I've found myself in too :(

Comment: Basically...no. Essentially, you're trying to impose a grid structure on something that isn't intended to be a grid-replacement. Flexbox may not be what you need here.

Comment: Even, depending on your size screen you'd have to render 2 items by row instead. Definitively you cant just find a way to solve it with the same HTML and CSS. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"Otherwise during the responsiveness I would have to eliminate the margins on odd / evens / first / last etc to ensure the entire container is taken up."*

You don't have to clear margin for hard-coded child elements. Here is the trick:

1. Add `overflow: hidden` on parent of flex container to avoid horizontal scroll.
2. Extend flex container with negative margin from both sides equal to margin applied on flex child on either side.
3. Add same left / right margin on flex child.

```css
.row {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto 20px;
  background: #ebebeb;
}

ul {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
}

li {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background: #999;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  ul {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    display:flex;
    margin: 0 -1%;
  }
  li {
    margin-right: 1%;
    margin-left: 1%;
    width: 48%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  li {
    width: 23%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row row--ideal">
  <h3>Ideal Result</h3>
  <ul>
    <li> Item 1 </li>
    <li> Item 2 </li>
    <li> Item 3 </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="row row--ideal">
  <h3>Ideal Result</h3>
  <ul>
    <li> Item 1 </li>
    <li> Item 2 </li>
    <li> Item 3 </li>
    <li> Item 4 </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I've tried this in conjunction with media queries to have all panels at 100% on mobile and 48% on tablet and 23% on desktop. This approach is still defining a margin of 18px, therefore, when on tablet they cannot sit side by side because I would need to remove or adjust the margin.

Comment: @MegaTron Please check this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Muhammad_Usman/w3absqkk/). Is it what you want?

Comment: That's it! Thank you for taking the time to investigate this. Very much appreciated. If you're able to update your answer, I'll mark it straight away!